# Get element in Angular view using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm relatively new to Angular, and suspect I am not grasping a concept.

What I want to do:
Load main view. Click a button on main view which loads a different view. Use jQuery (or any other method) to return an input field in that new view, so I can change the text of the input.

Angular view, which loads after I click a button in the main view:

```
<input type="text" id="contact_name" ng-model="contact_name"></input>
```

Function that is supposed to change the text of the input field

```
function loadInputs(){
    $('#contact_name').val('test'));
}
```

What I tried so far, both of these are being called from the controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
  loadInputs();
});
```

and

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', tempContact.loadInputs());
```

Neither of which worked. What is the "angular way" of doing this?

Comment: The angular is not to use jquery selectors and just use the mvvm pattern. `$scope.contact_nam='test'`

Comment: Read [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you that do not implement this with jQuery. Just modify your code slightly.

```
       $scope.loadInputs=function()
       {
             $scope.contact_name='test';
       };
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can't believe it was this simple. Thanks!